# Syncronizing object to avoid a null pointer exception on Muiti Thread enviroment

Tags: java, android

I'm having a null pointer exception in my app. The null pointer is happening even after checking if the object isn't null..

My class is accessed by different threads. So, I believe the class-member object is being set to null after the if statement. So, when I actually try to access it, it might be null already leading to the NPE (null pointer exception).

Below is my code:

```
private MyCustomListener listener;

public void setListener(@Nullable final MyCustomListener listener) {
    mMyCustomListener = listener;
}

public void onEvent() {
    if (mMyCustomListener != null) {
        .... // Some code
        listener.execute(); // Null Pointer Exception at this line
    }
}
```

What I have tried:

```
private MyCustomListener listener;

private static final Object mListenerSync = new Object();

public void setListener(@Nullable final MyCustomListener listener) {
    synchronized(mListenerSync) {
        mMyCustomListener = listener;
    }
}

public void onEvent() {
    synchronized(mListenerSync) {
        if (mMyCustomListener != null) {
            .... // Some small code
            listener.execute(); // Null Pointer Exception
        }
    }
}
```

Basically, I have two threads. One that set/unset the listener to receive `onEvent()` notifications. The second thread is responsible to produce `onEvent()` calls. I would like that the listener from the first thread stop being invoked as soon as I set the listener to null.

So, I would like to request your support to confirm following points.

1. Will my code be tread-safe now? Or at least I'm avoiding the NPE.
2. mListenerSync object must be static?

I'm testing my code and I didn't observed any side-effect such as a dead-lock.. However, I'm not sure if this code will fix my issue given it is hard to reproduce.

Answer (score 0):

If you're sure that the reason is other threads setting the listener to `null`, you can rectify it easily with a local variable and no additional synchronization. Make the variable `transient` if you're actually changing the listener to ensure visibility. Although I have a feeling this isn't the reason for your errors

```
private transient MyCustomListener listener;

public void onEvent() {
    MyCustomListener listener = myCustomListener;
    if (listener != null) {
        .... // Some code
        listener.execute();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks the atteantion. I updated the question a bit with more info. I liked your approach. It certainly fixes the NPE. However, I would like to avoid a possible additional invocation to listener.execute() after set the listener to null. Do you think that is possible?

Comment: @W0rmH0le certainly it's possible, but this is far more lightweight and simple, so it would only make sense to choose a complex version (i.e. full sync mutex, as you have done in your second version which looks fine) if you really **need** to avoid the minute chance that the thread scheduler makes the local variable and the instance variable be out of sync. If you only *would like* to avoid it, then wouldn't you rather like nicer code?